# Rainbow on a curve

Tags: plotting, color

Writing:

```
f[{x_, y_, z_}] = x^3 + y^3 + z^3;

r[u_] = {1/2 + 1/2 Cosh[u],
         Sqrt[2]/2 Sinh[u],
         1/2 - 1/2 Cosh[u]};
{min, max} = {-ArcSinh[2 Sqrt[2]], ArcSinh[2 Sqrt[2]]};

ParametricPlot3D[r[u], {u, min, max},
                 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
                 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u},
                 ColorData["Rainbow"][f[r[u]]]],
                 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
                 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},   
                 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow",
                {NMinValue[{f[r[u]], min <= u <= max}, u],                                                         
                 NMaxValue[{f[r[u]], min <= u <= max}, u]}}]]
```

I get:

[image]

And I do not understand why in this case the color scale is so badly distributed. Is there a way to make it easier to read?

Comment: You could try rescaling the values you pass to `ColorData`: `fmax=NMaxValue[{f[r[u]], min <= u <= max}, u];` then include `ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u},
                 ColorData["Rainbow"][f[r[u]]/fmax]]`

Comment: What exactly do you want? Your function $f$ is fairly flat over most of your range, then with a large increase towards the end of your range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want?:

```
f[{x_, y_, z_}] = x^3 + y^3 + z^3;

r[u_] = {1/2 + 1/2 Cosh[u], Sqrt[2]/2 Sinh[u], 1/2 - 1/2 Cosh[u]};
{min, max} = {-ArcSinh[2 Sqrt[2]], ArcSinh[2 Sqrt[2]]};
{fmin, fmax} = {NMinValue[{f[r[u]], min <= u <= max}, u], 
   NMaxValue[{f[r[u]], min <= u <= max}, u]};

Legended[
 ParametricPlot3D[r[u], {u, min, max}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z, u}, ColorData[{"Rainbow", {fmin, fmax}}][f[r[u]]]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}], BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {fmin, fmax}}]]
```

[image]

You need to manually rescale the `ColorFunction` input, if you use `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`, but that messes up `BarLegend`.  Here is an alternative to `Legended`, using `PlotLegends` with an undocumented option to `BarLegend`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[r[u], {u, min, max}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, u}, ColorData[{"Rainbow", {fmin, fmax}}][f[r[u]]]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {fmin, fmax}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> True]]
(* give the same output *)
```

Comment: Updated to use the automatic rescaling feature of the `ColorData[]` gradients (`ColorData[{"Rainbow", {fmin, fmax}}][f[r[u]]]`), which I somehow forgot about for a little while.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
f[{x_, y_, z_}] := x^3 + y^3 + z^3;
r[u_] := {1/2 + 1/2 Cosh[u], Sqrt[2]/2 Sinh[u], 1/2 - 1/2 Cosh[u]};
{min, max} = {-ArcSinh[2 Sqrt[2]], ArcSinh[2 Sqrt[2]]};
mu = 0.2; 
mi = NMinValue[{f[r[u]], min <= u <= max}, u];
ma = NMaxValue[{f[r[u]], min <= u <= max}, u];
ParametricPlot3D[r[u], {u, min, max}, 
BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u}, 
ColorData["Rainbow"][mu f[r[u]]]],
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", 
{mi, mu(ma-mi)}}]]
```

[image]